# The specified version of Microsoft.NetCore.App or Microsoft.AspNetCore.App was not found

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have deployed my app on a production machine. I am publishing Release, win-x64 and --self-contained true.
I have installed .net core 3.1.7 restarted the VPS and I am getting:

> The specified version of Microsoft.NetCore.App or Microsoft.AspNetCore.App was not found.

`dotnet --info` returns:

```
  It was not possible to find any installed .NET Core SDKs
  Did you mean to run .NET Core SDK commands? Install a .NET Core SDK from:
      https://aka.ms/dotnet-download

Host (useful for support):
  Version: 3.1.7
  Commit:  fcfdef8d6b

.NET Core SDKs installed:
  No SDKs were found.

.NET Core runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.7 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.7 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]

To install additional .NET Core runtimes or SDKs:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet-download
```

my .csproj file is the following

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
<PropertyGroup>
```

Anyone knows why am I getting this error?

Comment: Could you please tell me how you host your application? On IIS or server directly?

Comment: You need a hosting bundle, if IIS is used

Comment: I answered a similar question today, please follow this check-list: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63466234/14072498

Comment: I found the issue. I deleted this file SOS_README.md and when I enabled stdlog I got the error that SOS_README.md is missing. Misleading error message.

Comment: If you are publishing as self-contained then you don't need .NET Core installed on the host machine

Comment: In my case (.NET 5 Web App), I had this excerpt in web.config: `<aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\MyWeb.dll" />`. The error was, that "MyWeb.dll" did not exist (I renamed it recently). So I adjusted the `arguments` to point to the correct DLL and then, that error went away.

Answer (score 2):

From my end, I was facing this issue when trying to start IIS server on my local machine. I downloaded [.NET Core 3.1 SDK](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/3.1) and the problem is now solved.

Comment: The same issue affects 5.0 and I solved it by installing the bundle and the 5.0 sdk.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add this in your `.csproj` file:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <RollForward>Major</RollForward>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).