# .Net Core 3.1 App not starting automatically in IIS after deployment

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-3.1, .net-core-3.1

I migrated an Asp.net core web app from .net core 2.2 to 3.1 and deployed it to IIS. The app was running automatically on 2.2 with the below settings but is not running until an API call is made.

I had the AppPool settings set to

.Net Clr Version: v4.0
StartMode: Always Running
Idle Timeout: 0

And the WebApp Settings
EnablePreload: true

Although I found nothing being changed regarding hosting on Microsoft.

Has anyone also faced such issues? Any help here would be appreciated

Comment: Did you check your launchsetting.json file ?

Comment: Please see my IIS check-list just to make sure everything is OK. Net Clr Version: v4.0 looks suspicious, but I don't have an IIS server right now to compare with.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/63466234/14072498

Comment: I compared with your link and changed it to NoManagedCode. It didn't work although. I copied the settings which worked for .NetCore 2.2

Comment: Have you installed latest hosting bundle for asp.net Core 3.1, because your app will need it.

Comment: yes that is in place

Comment: Can you add the generated web.config to your question, just want to check it is ok.

Comment: Added AppInitialization section in system.webserver with following body 
<system.webServer>
        <applicationInitialization doAppInitAfterRestart="true">
            <clear />
            <add initializationPage="**path of the url{/echo}**" hostName="**{Url Host of the application}**" />
        </applicationInitialization>
    </system.webServer>